# What it is and how to read a distribution equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, normal-distribution, filters

disclaimer: just assume that I know nothing but basic algebraic math and some notions of linear algebra .

I'm trying to literally read the equations about distributions and to me they don't make sense mathematically speaking .

Take one of the most popular one, the 2D gaussian distribution, you start with this math object

$$G(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}e^{\frac{-x^2+y^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

Informally speaking we can leave $\sigma$ aside because it's a parameter that the user can tune and it doesn't change much in the writing ( it's a constant ) .

Now I'm trying to derive the $(x,y)$ values on the left side so I can use this 2D gaussian distribution but I really don't understand the writing on the right to begin with .

In school when you don't have enough terms for your unknowns the equation is deemed unsolvable, here I have basically the same situation with a bunch of constants, $x^2$ and $y^2$ on the right, and the pair $(x,y)$ that I would like to derive on the left : how do I solve and read this ?

With some development of the 2D Gaussian distribution you can even find this other object

$$
\frac{1}{273}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  4 &  7 &  4 & 1\\
4 & 16 & 26 & 16 & 4\\
7 & 26 & 41 & 26 & 7\\
4 & 16 & 26 & 16 & 4\\
1 &  4 &  7 &  4 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

which I know how to use but I don't know how to derive and what it means in relation to the starting point, the 2D Gaussian equation.

It looks like some kind of unit normalization with the $\frac{1}{273}$ aside because it's a linear system after all and you can multiply and "take factors out"; but this is just my speculation .

Given the initial equation how I can go forward and derive the "Gaussian matrix" ? What are the rules ?

Comment: The second object is probably a quantization of a sampling of the first object on some grid for some $\sigma$. Imagine there is an $x$ and a $y$ hiding beneath each number of the second object.